# Postman: configuration with symfony

Tags: symfony, postman, symfony-3.3

I am trying to use [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) to make some requests to my API and the problem is that always I get a 404 response even when the browser gives me a 200.

Here is my Postman request:

[image]

It's very confusing. How could I fix that? Is there a problem with Postman, my Apache, my PHP?

Working with xampp (PHP 7.1.1) and the desktop version of Postman.

**Update #1:**

The problem seems to be the Postman as it is sending the request via proxy even with that option disabled.

When I send a request to google.com.cu all works fine (it shouldn't be because my connection is behind a proxy and Postman don't know that config).

After that, I unplugged my network, and Postman was not been able to send more requests (all good for external requests) but not for my localhost.

Does Postman need an internet connection to send localhost requests?

**Update #2:**

The server browser response is OK (symfony welcome page).

[image]

Comment: can you try Apache server configuration for your project then

Comment: try removing "/" from the end of the url

Comment: @Robert is the default config. I don't have a virtual host yet. I just tried with the built in server and getting the 503 error. the problem remains with and without "/"

Comment: i have updated my post above

Comment: can You  share the browser response please ?. If you can do it with an image that would be great !

Comment: updated, all from server is working OK, it seems the postman is sending the request via a non configured proxy. and depends on my network connection. It's crazy why should need the network connection to test localhost

Comment: Seems postman is forced to use a proxy. I'm using now soap UI 5.4.0 and all is working fine. I turned off the proxy option and I can see the response as application/json. Postman still crashing. should I delete my post?

Answer (score 1):

I can see in your request that you don’t supply a port number, just localhost and then the route - Is this intentional?

You could try just `localhost:<port>/<your_route>`

Comment: localhost and localhost:80 is the same default virtual host, the problem remains

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I thought I was going crazy. :)